# SURF for a given point

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, surf

I'm trying to find the point `[x,y]` from an image A in an image B (just that point). I've calculated `[x,y]` from an own algorithm. And now I'm trying to find the point in the image B through [SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html). I've seen the ['find_obj.cpp'](http://code.opencv.org/svn/gsoc2012/denoising/trunk/opencv-2.4.2/samples/c/find_obj.cpp), but I couldn't modify it so it does what I want.
Also used code below:

```
cv::initModule_nonfree(); 
cv::Mat image( 256, 256, CV_8UC1);
cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor desc(400);
vector<cv::KeyPoint> pnt;
pnt.push_back(cv::KeyPoint(x, y, 50));
cv::Mat descriptors_pnt;
desc.compute(image, pnt, descriptors_pnt);
```

But it returns a memory access error.

Now I'm completely lost. I don't even know if SURF is going to work for me or if I have to find another algorithm to do that.

Comment: Does your image actually hold any data?

Comment: Not in that code, which is what i found on internet. No changes.
I've tried many things, with images full of data ;) and still not working.
My question is if SURF is gonna accept to match points from a point given or i have to use another algorithm (im trying SIFT right now)

Comment: Could you try to first extract the features with a detector and if that works, then try without the detector?
As in
cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(image, keypoints);

Comment: Btw, I assume x1, y1 is well within the bounds of the image?

Comment: detector.detect gives me an error on xutility file.
Yeah, i use x1 and y1 in other part of the program and both have valid values.